# Solution of heat equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

We consider the heat equation 
$$
u_t= c^2(u_{xx} + u_{yy})
$$
1. Write the differential equations satisfied by $X, Y$ and $T$ where $u(x,y,t)= X(x) Y(y) T(t)$. 
2. Calculate the solution of this equations that satisfy $u(0,y,t)=u(a,y,t)=u(x,b,t)=0$.

For the question 1, i find that the equations satisfied by $X, Y$ and $T$ are: 
$$
T'(t)=k T(t),
$$
$$
Y''(y)=lY(y)
$$
$$
X''(x)= (\dfrac{k}{c^2}-l) X(x)
$$
where $c$, $k$ and $l$ are constants.

My difficultie is in the question 2. How we calculate the solution $u$ that satisfies $u(0,y,t)=u(a,y,t)=u(x,b,t)=0$?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You need to solve the ODEs, obtain a series solution for $u$ and then apply your boundary conditions. And two more things; 1. It is easier to keep the $c^{2}$ with your ODE in $t$ 2. You are missing a boundary condition and an initial condition.

Comment: But we have three ODEs

Comment: And? You need to solve all 3.

Answer (score 0):

This version of the $2D$ heat equation, given your boundary conditions is equivalent to a thin rectangular plate made of some thermally conductive material whose area is $ab$. The Dirichlet boundary conditions you quote then physically, t correspond to holding the temperature along the edges of the plate at $0$.

Plugging the ansatz you quote into the heat equation then yields the correct result you obtain. Then putting in the boundary conditions you arrive at the following:

\begin{align}
X''-\lambda X &= 0 \tag{1}\\
Y''-\mu Y &= 0 \tag{2}\\
T'-c^2(\lambda + \mu)T \tag{3} &= 0
\end{align}
Let $\lambda + \mu = \alpha$.
Then $(3)$ solves to $T_{mn}=c_{mn}e^{-\alpha_{mn}t}$ and $(1), (2)$ becomes $X_{m}(x)=\sin \lambda_{m} x$, $Y_{n}(y)=\sin \mu_{n}y$. Also one has $\lambda_{m}=m \pi/a$ and $\mu_n = n \pi/b$

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand. I obtain that $$T'=k T(t)$$ and you obtained that $$T'-c^2(\lambda +\mu) T=0$$. How you obtained this? Please